# Tess4J: The result String can't be parsed to int

Tags: java, string, tesseract, parseint, tess4j

I'm scanning single letters and numbers. All the numbers should be parsed into numbers[]. But it's always catching the exception. For Example: result is "3" but I can't parse it for some reason. I also tried to check if it's actually "3" with an if statement but I also got a false returned. Can someone explain me why it isn't working?

```
File imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Nils\\IdeaProjects\\untitled8\\Images\\Cutted\\"+i+m+".png");
            ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();  // JNA Interface Mapping
            // ITesseract instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping
            instance.setDatapath("C:/Users/Nils/Desktop/blum/Tess4J/tessdata"); // path to tessdata directory

            try {
                String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
                try {

                    resultI=Integer.parseInt(result);
                    numbers[0] = resultI;

                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    numbers[0]=0;
                }
            } catch (TesseractException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Sounds like `result` actually  _isn't_ "3". I believe the `NumberFormatException` you are suppressing will tell you what the string was.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3
seems like there are a bunch of spaces after 3..

Comment: Tesseract's string ouput contains EOL characters as line delimiters. You may need to trim them before parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.

```
if(result.length()>1)
    result=result.substring(0,1);
```

Delets everything that caused errors but keeps the number I want to separate.